# PRAW: Progress bar for replace_more_comments()?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I've been using the Python Reddit API Wrapper (PRAW) to gather specific comments from Reddit, and one of the functions I'm commonly using is `replace_more_comments()` to gather all of the comments for a thread.

Some of these threads are quite large -- 10,000 comments, for example -- and take a while to gather all of the comments. Is there a way to show a progress bar for `replace_more_comments()`?

Here's a minimal working code sample:

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit('MSU vs Nebraska game')
submission = r.get_submission(submission_id='3rxx3y')
flat_comments = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(submission.comments)
submission.replace_more_comments(limit=None, threshold=0)
all_comments = submission.comments
flat_comments = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(submission.comments)
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in implementation of `replace_more_comments` does not support this, but you could write your own version.  For reference, [here's the original implementation](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/d0893c1d0320f5301d847fc70afe2c940fecf1b4/praw/objects.py#L1254-L1303).

I don't know how to draw an actual progress bar; you'll have to write `update_progress_bar`.  I also haven't tested this code, and it might not work at all.

```python
def replace_more_comments(self, post):
    """Update the comment tree by replacing instances of MoreComments."""
    if post._replaced_more:
        return

    more_comments = post._extract_more_comments(comment.comments)

    # Estimate the total number of comments
    count = 0
    for item in more_comments:
        count += item.count

    update_progress_bar(0, count)

    num_loaded = 0

    while more_comments:
        item = heappop(more_comments)

        # Fetch new comments and decrease remaining if a request was made
        new_comments = item.comments(update=False)
        elif new_comments is None:
            continue

        # Re-add new MoreComment objects to the heap of more_comments
        for more in self._extract_more_comments(new_comments):
            more._update_submission(post)  # pylint: disable=W0212
            heappush(more_comments, more)
        # Increase progress bar
        num_loaded += len(new_comments)
        update_progress_bar(num_loaded, count)
        # Insert the new comments into the tree
        for comment in new_comments:
            post._insert_comment(comment)

    post._replaced_more = True
```